# rename selector using postcss

Tags: css, css-selectors, postcss

I have a CSS file that contains tag such as "figure" and I want to rename it to "svg". The CSS contains these styles in different format.

```
body,figure{margin-top:10px}
figure {padding-top:5px;}
.custom-figure{padding: 20px;}
```

My first approach was to use regex to rename `figure` to `svg`, but that will also capture `custom-figure` which I don't want to touch.

I looked in https://github.com/fi3ework/postcss-rename-selector, but keep getting:

```
import postcss from 'postcss'
       ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

any idea what I could do to get unblocked here?

Comment: If all you ever want is to permanently rename figure to svg I would do it manually and  leave postcss out of it. That is not the purpose if it and also for the sake when working with the files. I'm not good at regex else I would give you one but in Visual Studio Code and other OEMS you can do a regex search, that would let you finegrane it and leave out the "-" part before figure. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/using-regular-expressions-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019

Comment: If you need it really fast I would just do a search and replace for 1. `figure` 2. `.custom-svg` > `.custom-figure`

Comment: @Dejan.S : I am using regex'es now and they work albeit bit clunky. The only reason to try postcss was to see if there's a cleaner way to make this happen..

Comment: I would use my second approach for a quick fix and be done with it.